# Is the "my little time" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the "my little time" grammatical?  If so, what is its grammatical principle?

I have little time.

I miss my little time.

I only know that the first sentence is correct but I don't know whether the second sentence is correct or not? If not, how can I modify it to materalise grammatical?

Comment: It may be worth adding an example like "It's my time!" or "My time is now!" to the question. Those expressions are valid combinations of *time* with *my,* and mean "The time is now right for me to [do whatever it is]".

Comment: 'Little' in ''I have little time' is used in the sense of 'not much' - 'I have little time in which to get ready'. So your second sentence doesn't really work.

Comment: I think it's close to grammatical. This would be idiomatic: "I cherish what little time I have left".

Comment: In 'I have little time', _little_ is the quantifier usage. This doesn't usually sit well with possessive pronouns, especially without 'padding': there are examples of 'I want to enjoy my little time left with you' say on the internet. // In 'I miss my little dog', _little_ is the adjective.

Answer (score 1):

As Kate Bunting said in her comment above:

"I have little time" = "I don't have much time"

Compare to "I have few regrets" = "I don't have many regrets"
(The difference much/many is to do with *countability* - you can count regrets, but time exists as a continuum)

I also agree with Steve Bennett's suggestion for the alternative.

As Kate said, "little time" = "not much time", and you can't say "my not much time".